# Defining DateDiff for a calculated column in a datatable

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the column DateTimeExpired, and I would like to create another column called "Expired" which will show "Yes" or "No" according to the expiration date - "Yes" if the date has already passed.
I wrote this:

```
DataColumn colExpirationDate = new DataColumn("DateTimeExpired", typeof(DateTime));
DataColumn colExpired = new DataColumn("Expired", typeof(string), "IIF(DateDiff(DateTimeExpired, date())>= 0,'No','Yes')");
```

But I get an exception "The expression contains undefined function call DateDiff()."

(please note  that I always want to get the row, no matter if it's expired or not)

How do I set the column's text to the correct form?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use your DateDiff function there. See the following documentation for the Expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.90).aspx

Comment: Same here .. not sure - but if you can, try getdate() and not date()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M.A Hanin pointed out in his comment, it looks like DateDiff cannot be used in [DataColumn Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.90).aspx). You could try building the calculated column into the underlying table instead (if you are using MS Sql or similar)

edit:
There is no function to get 'today', but assuming that the DataColumn you are adding will only exist for a few hours, you could build in todays date as a constant, and then use comparison operators instead of DateDiff

Try this:

```
DataColumn colExpirationDate = new DataColumn("DateTimeExpired", typeof(DateTime));
DataColumn colExpired = new DataColumn("Expired", typeof(string),
    String.Format("IIF(DateTimeExpired > #{0}#,'No','Yes')",
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")));
```

Note this will only work if your DataColumn is only retained in memory for less than a day.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm looking for an alternative. I remember that it was something like #date#, but don't know exactly. Thanks.

Comment: There are no useful functions available, but you might be able to do it by substituting todays date as a constant, see edit above

Comment: The code above throws this exception:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I should have used capital MMM for the date format. Have edited the code, try it again.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is convert your two date columns using `Date.ToOADate` to doubles then subtract.

I use `ToOADate` to populate hidden columns for each date column.