# adding a calculated column for date difference in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datediff, calculated-columns

I need to add a calculated column to my DataTable that works out the number of days different between a given date and the current date. I've googled this but cannot find anything this specific.

I've tried using the formula i have on the SQL side, but it doesn't work when building a DataTable in .net c#

```
OrderHeaders.Columns.Add("AGE", typeof(string), "datediff(day,[DATE_ADDED],getdate())");
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643752/defining-datediff-for-a-calculated-column-in-a-datatable

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this

But you should have a dataset or localdatabase connection like SQL I will assume that you got it and name it Totaldataset.

Easily done I know it's too late answer but maybe it help some new readers.

I will post the code down

Comment: Datacolumn column = new Datacolumn (); 
column.Columnname = "Total"; 
Totaldataset.Tables[0].Columns.["Total"].Expression = "a+b";

Comment: That was example may be help :)