# Trying to use the DateDiff function in a dataset column expression

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I'm rather new to VB.net (DataSet objects in particular), so hopefully my question makes sense.  I would like to calculate the date difference (in days) between a given date column and today's date and put the calculated value in a new/custom column.  When I attempt to use the DateDiff function in the column expression (in the Properties page), I get an 'undefined function call' error.  I can use simple functions like Len, but not more complex functions.  Is there a way to accomplish this programmatically?  Thank you

Comment: Same question in c#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643752/defining-datediff-for-a-calculated-column-in-a-datatable

Comment: I found another StackOverflow answer (issue 13544462) to solve my issue.  I'm now able to programmatically populate a DataGridView object.  Now working on incorporating DateDiff function into imbedded SQL statement.  Closing issue.